# How to successfully install requirements.txt (Python modules) file in Docker Windows Container?

Tags: python, windows, docker, containers, connection-timeout

WITH ***dns*** field in JSON file - I am facing the below error when I tried to install requirements.txt file in docker. (Using company's system)

[image]

**Note:** When I try to install same file in Linux based container then I do not get this error. I am using windows container because I have pywin32 library that works only on windows.

WITHOUT ***dns*** field in the JSON file I am getting below error:

[image]

**P.S.:** I have gone through numerous blogs and stackoverflow questions but did not get solution to my use case.

Comment: The error complains about a connection error. This has nothing to do with Windows. Python and pip run on Windows just fine. I'm working on multiple ETL scripts right now, with multiple environments, packages, pytest etc

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, I am able to work using internet connection without any issues! Does it have to do with firewall or some other getaway? I am using company's system.

Comment: But does the *container* have connectivity? Is DNS configured? The error clearly says that the connection to pypi.org timed out after 15 seconds which is the same as the DNS timeout. Remove that command and start the container with an interactive terminal. Can you ping `pypi.org` or use `nslookup pypi.org` inside it?

Comment: pip usually needs to be configured to use a proxy in these types of network

Comment: If you google for `windows server core container DNS` you'll find several questions in Docker forums. The container's access to DNS was blocked by antivirus, firewalls or VPNs which blocked the unknown machine they saw trying to connect.

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the DNS with the `--dns` switch or creating a network explicitly. This is discussed in [this Docker discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/dns-broken-on-docker-desktop-for-windows/130121).Windows Server Core is a *very* cut-down environment. DNS resolution first tries to use the Docker DNS server to connect to other containers and when that fails it tries other servers. [DNS delegation should work](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/397) but using a custom network lets you specify who talks to whom directly

Comment: I checked with ping and nslookup, it is working from CMD. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @FlyingTeller where and how should we configure proxy? In daemon.json file? If it is then I have tried adding IPv4 address in the JSON file.

Comment: From *inside* the container? In that case, did you try executing `pip install` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let me check the docker discussion which you have linked. Will circle back after reading through it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how to ping from insider a container? If the build is not created, then how do we access container?

Comment: you could shorten your dockerfile enought that it gives you a running container. For testing the network, it does not matter if it actually contains your application or not

Comment: Remove the `RUN` line so the image builds, start it with `docker run -it ... cmd.exe`  or `... Powershell.exe` and check whether you can use ping, nslookup or pip inside it

Comment: Got it! Let me try that!

Comment: I tried small flask app on Linux Based Container to test and it is working fine.

Comment: I read the links shared by @Panagiotis. In all of those it is about when they are running the docker container. However, I am getting error during building an image. In this step I can't use --network switch or --dns for windows container.

Comment: I tried without dns field and it is showing error shown in the image from the post.